Animated View deactivating touchability
So i have this component in my RN application. when I try to animated the component by wrapping it in an animated view, the touchable opacity in the component stops working. it does not even respond to touches but as soon as i take out the animated view, everything works fine and the component is clickable.
`<Animated.View
style={{
width: width,
justifyContent: "center",
alignItems: "center",
position: "absolute",
top: height * 0.1,
transform: [{ translateY }],
backgroundColor: theme.colors.mainBlue,
paddingBottom: 15,
}}
        pointerEvents={"box-none"}
    >
        <View style={styles.switchBar}>
            {options.map((option) => (
                <TouchableOpacity
                    key={option}
                    onPress={() => handleSelect(option)}
                    style={[
                        styles.option,
                        selected === option ? styles.selected : styles.unselected,
                    ]}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={[
                            styles.optionText,
                            selected === option ? styles.selectedText : styles.unselectedText,
                        ]}
                    >
                        {option}
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            ))}
        </View>
     </Animated.View>`

there is the code snipet. the touchable opacity just does not work when the animated view is on but when i take it out, it does.
I tried PointersEvent="Box-none" bur that did not work.
i also set useNativeDriver={false} on the animation but that also did not fix it.
